# MYSQL splitting two different values in a single column into two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp1yr.png)

I am trying to make a single query where I split the two values of 'Y' and 'N' into two different columns based on the id and count the total number of times they appear for each id.

```
SELECT exerciseId, count(frustrated) Frustrated from selfreportfrustration where frustrated = 'Y' group by exerciseId;

SELECT exerciseId, count(frustrated) NotFrustrated from selfreportfrustration where frustrated = 'N' group by exerciseId;
```

So far I have only managed to make one query for each value, but I was hoping to be able to shorten it into one query for my program to work.

Comment: You can use union between both queries

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select exerciseId, sum(frustrated = 'Y') as Frustrated,
       sum(frustrated = 'N') as NotFrustrated
from selfreportfrustration
group by exerciseId;
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll put the 'Y' or 'N' in another column:

```
SELECT frustrated, exerciseId,
  count(frustrated) Frustrated
from selfreportfrustration
group by frustrated, exerciseId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) aggregation with [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) conditional function.

Try:

```
SELECT exerciseId, 
       COUNT( IF(frustrated = 'Y', exerciseId, NULL) ) AS frustrated, 
       COUNT( IF(frustrated = 'N', exerciseId, NULL) ) AS not_frustrated 
FROM selfreportfrustration 
GROUP BY exerciseId
```